React shows wrong value when using useState

Procedure:

const nextValue = counter + limit_counter; -> In here, nextValue = 2

console.log("haha", nextValue);

setCounter(nextValue); -> nextValue =2 for counter

console.log({ counter }); //but when I check, why is counter = 1 ??????


Example images:
enter image description here

There is App root:
enter image description here

There is MainCounter component:
enter image description here


Could you explain me the reason why?? Thank you ^^
enter image description here
const nextValue = counter + limit_counter; -> In here, nextValue = 2

console.log("haha", nextValue);

setCounter(nextValue); -> nextValue =2 for counter

console.log({ counter }); //but when I check, why is counter = 1 ??????


I think in line 4, counter should equal to '2' or I missed something?

Does this answer your question? The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

React's setState function is async, which means you have to do something like this :
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter);
}, [counter ]);


Use the callback version of the setCounter function.
You will need an effect that listens for changes to counter.
Note: In your provided code (screenshot), your CounterMain component is a controlled component. It manages its own state, so you do not need a counter in App. Also, increaseValue is unused.


const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const CounterMain = ({ increaseValue }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const limitCounter = 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("New value set to:", counter); // After update
  }, [counter]);

  const handleIncreaseValue = () => {
    setCounter((currValue) => {
      const nextValue = currValue + limitCounter;
      console.log("Setting new value", nextValue); // Stage it
      return nextValue;
    });
  };

  return (
    <button className="bg-cyan-400 p-2" onClick={handleIncreaseValue}>
      {counter}
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CounterMain />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



Note: Your App and CounterMain components both have a counter state. If you need to hoist the state, move it to App.


const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const CounterMain = ({ increaseValue, value }) => {
  const limitCounter = 1;

  const handleIncreaseValue = () => {
    const nextValue = value + limitCounter;
    console.log("Setting new value", nextValue); // Stage it
    increaseValue(nextValue);
  };

  return (
    <button className="bg-cyan-400 p-2" onClick={handleIncreaseValue}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("New value set to:", counter); // After update
  }, [counter]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CounterMain value={counter} increaseValue={setCounter} />
      <div>Value: {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



If you want to share the state, you can use a context:


const { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const CounterContext = createContext(null);
const CounterDispatchContext = createContext(null);

const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(countReducer, 0);
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={count}>
      <CounterDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CounterDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useCounter = () => useContext(CounterContext);
const useCounterDispatch = () => useContext(CounterDispatchContext);

const countReducer = (count, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment': return count + action.amount;
    default: {
      throw Error('Unknown action: ' + action.type);
    }
  }
};

const CounterMain = () => {
  const count = useCounter();
  const dispatch = useCounterDispatch();
  const limitCounter = 1;

  const handleIncreaseValue = () => {
    const nextValue = count + limitCounter;
    console.log("Setting new value", nextValue); // Stage it
    dispatch({ type: 'increment', amount: limitCounter });
  };

  return (
    <button className="bg-cyan-400 p-2" onClick={handleIncreaseValue}>
      {count}
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const count = useCounter();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("New value set to:", count); // After update
  }, [count]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CounterMain />
      <div>Value: {count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render((
  <CounterProvider>
    <App />
  </CounterProvider>
));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



